# Best way to set a solid-color background on a SurfaceView

Tags: java, android, performance, android-canvas, surfaceview

I am currently using `drawColor` to draw a solid color on a canvas in a SurfaceView, but I am looking to optimize performance and I am not sure that this is the best way. If I had an image background, I would put it in a separate view and only draw it once, then use another SurfaceView to do animations; is this necessary if it's just a simple solid background?

Would redrawing a solid background between animations reduce performance, and if so, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: afaik drawPaint is the fastest

Comment: If you're that concerned about performance, you should be using hardware-accelerated rendering.  You can't do that with Canvas on a SurfaceView -- you either need to define a custom View, or render on the Surface with GLES.